# How do you mask sensitive request params in gqlgen?

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen, pii

I am currently using gqlgen and would like to log request parameters for error investigation purposes.

While I know how to access request parameters like below, I am concerned that this way may log sensitive information such as email addresses or passwords.

```
srv.SetErrorPresenter(func(ctx context.Context, err error) *gqlerror.Error {
    goc := graphql.GetOperationContext(ctx)

    fmt.Println(goc.Variables) // i can access request params here, but these might include sensitive data

    gqlErr := graphql.DefaultErrorPresenter(ctx, err)
    return gqlErr
})
```

Therefore, I believe data masking is necessary.
What would be a good approach to handle this?

Comment: If you know the names of the sensitive params, you could check for those in `goc.Variables` and then mask the values as needed. Alternatively (or in addition), if you're using a log aggregator service/tool, you may be able to enable masking there.